# how to rewrite socket into websockets

Tags: sockets, websocket, python-asyncio

I'm trying to rewrite socket python code using the websockets API so I can run things asynchronously. However, my understanding of sockets, asyncio, and websockets, is not great so I have no intuition how it should go, googling doesn't help, and the websockets documentation is sparse.

My socket code is very simple and looks like this:

```
BLESKA_ADDR='blerka.uva.cts.cz'
BLESKA_PORT=51120

with socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM) as sin:
    sin.connect((BLESKA_ADDR, BLESKA_PORT))
    while True:
        trig_iso = str(sin.recv(256), 'utf-8').strip()
```

When I read the websockets documentation I see no reference to "AF_INET" or "SOCK_STREAM" (I don't really understand these in the first place, I was given this code). and the websocket.recv() method doesn't seem to take an argument (where socket.recv, as seen here, does).

Any advice or resources would be helpful